# image inside star div

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
#star12 {
background: blue;
width: 80px;
height: 80px;
position: relative;
}
#star12:before, #star12:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
background: blue;
}
#star12:before {
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
-o-transform: rotate(30deg);
}
#star12:after {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(60deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(60deg);
-o-transform: rotate(60deg);
}
</style>

<div id="star12" >
</div>
```

This code for a star type div. It outputs a star div.  I want to dispalay an image inside this star div. Is it possible? please help me friends.
I need to display an image in a div in a variety format.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please be more specific, help us help you.

Comment: i need to put an image inside a star div

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that's what's causing this but I think `transform`ed elements become higher on the document (z index gets bigger) than their descendants as well - which is where a manual `z-index` would come in handy for the image itself. An arbitrary number should suffice, I find that 10 worked in this case; also keep in mind that in order to use `z-index`, `position` must be `relative` or `absolute` (instead of the default `static`).

So if you want an image inside that star just put an `<img />` element and give it a `position:relative; z-index: 10`.

HTML:

```
<div id="star12" >
    <img src="http://www.wallpixy.com/wp-content/uploads/boy-nature-animated-beatiful-samsung-galaxy-note-wallpapers.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#star12 img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yk4Dn/1/)

Comment: Thank you @Chen Asraf .It is working now. Thank you so mauch for your quick response.

Comment: but how... it needs 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `<img />` inside `<div id="star12">`

```
<div id="star12" >
    <img src="http://www.fastcocreate.com/multisite_files/cocreate/imagecache/slideshow-large/slideshow/2013/01/1682345-slide-slide-1-biz-stone-explains-how-he-turned-91-random-photos-into-a-movie.jpg" />
</div>
```

And apply appropriate css to the img,

```
img{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;    
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;        
}
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/yFnsy/)

Comment: @Ammu You're welcome, can you please accept the answer by hitting the arrow mark. Cheers :)

Comment: @ badZoke I have tried to do that. but requires 15 reputation for that. I am recently join here. :)